# How do you wait until a specific time of day?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I want to have Ignis drive me somewhere, but it's night and I can only drive manually. How do I wait until morning?

Also, if I have a nighttime hunt, how would I wait until night? I expect they're the same mechanism.

Comment: The nearby inn would probably do the trick but I don't want to spend gil.

Comment: Some of the hunts have given me the option to skip until nighttime. Others haven't. No clear pattern.

Comment: I saw that when taking the hunt, but now I want to wait in a different context.

Comment: Actually I think the wait option was added in the Day 0 patch... #PrereleaseStruggles

Answer (score 4):

There is no option to wait until specific time of day. You can camp/use hotel anytime, to wait until next day morning (6:00 AM). Also, when you take hunting job, where monsters appear only at night, game will suggest you to skip time until night starts (8:00 PM). Those are the only means to skip time I've found in game.

I'm not really sure about opposite situation with monsters - when you take job for monsters, which appear only on day, during night.

**Update:** please note, that while progressing through game, actual time of morning/night is changing (morning starts later, night starts earlier), so times specified above, are correct only for first few chapters.